# Why I am getting 404 when trying to open a file from My Documents folder?

Tags: php, apache

I am trying to connect PHP and MySQL. I am on an Ubuntu machine with MySQL, phpMyAdmin, and Apache installed. I am able to login to phpMyAdmin and see the databases.

I am trying to connect to the database with the following in my `DbConnection.php` file:

```
<?php

$dbServername = "localhost";
$dbUsername = "matt";
$dbPassword = "";
$dbName = "database";

$conn = mysqli_connect($dbServername, $dbUsername, $dbPassword, $dbName) or die("Couldn't connect");
echo "Connected to DB";
```

But when I go to "**localhost/DbConnection.php**" I get:

> 404 Not Found the requested URL was not found on this server.

I am not sure what this means or how I can troubleshoot this. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Where (the directory) do you put the DbConnection.php ?

Comment: Make sure apache is running

Comment: DbConnection.php is in my Documents>Labs>DbConnection.php. I made sure apache is running

Comment: MySQL <> SQL Server - please correct your tags.

Comment: Is your Apache configured with Documents>Labs as the document root?

Comment: Ahh that was the problem Markus. Did not know it had to be in a certain directory. Thank you